# Cannot not launch avd in emulator

Tags: android

When I try to launch emulator in Android studio,the error shows that 'Cannot launch AVD in emulator'
The screenshot is given below

[image: Exception]

Answer (score 3):

i am also facing this problem . i have the right solution for this
Go to create new emulator

emulated performance   graphis is "

> Auto

by default

You have to click on "Auto" and then dropdown is open" after the select "

> Software - Gles 2.0

And at last click on finish.

It will definitely solve your problem